Specifying different actions in reinforcement learning
I have a problem with my reinforcement learning project. The project is defined as follows.
The agent chooses a number and based on that number it should do a task in every state.
When the number of tasks accomplished by the agent exceeds that predefined number, the agent shouldn't win any other tasks.
In other words, the agent should play for winning and achieving something in each state when the number of acquired tasks is less than that pre-defined number and it should play for losing when the the number of acquired tasks exceeds that pre-defined number.
My solution is to define two actions for every task. One for losing and one for winning. This means the size of output layer of Q-network should be twice of a game that only requires winning every task. When the player needs to win (the number of acquired tasks is less than the pre-defined number) it should choose the winning action and when it needs to lose it should choose the losing action.
Is my understanding of the problem correct? I tried to train the network without separating the actions and my network always played for winning (even when the agent needs to lose in the remaining states) because the data sampled during training is biased towards winning.
How should I define the actions, rewards and transitions?
Could you help me? Sorry for my weak English.
Edit: The problem is that when I define two different actions, I don't know what to do with the terminal reward. Is the terminal state when the player achieves enough tasks or when it reaches the end of episode? In other words should I slice the episode into two episodes or not? I am really confused.

What “rewards” are you using to estimate the Q of losing actions?
